# Spring Data Neo4j custom query list params not use converter

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

NodeEntity:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "User")
public class UserNode {
    @GraphId
    private Long _gid;

    @Index(unique = true, primary = true)
    @Convert(ObjectIdConverter.class)
    private ObjectId id;
}
```

Converter:

```
public class ObjectIdConverter implements AttributeConverter<ObjectId, String>{
    @Override
    public String toGraphProperty(ObjectId value) {
        return ObjectIdUtils.compressed(value);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId toEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return ObjectIdUtils.uncompress(value);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<UserNode> {
    @Query("MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN {0} RETURN user")
    List<UserNode> findByIdIn(List<ObjectId> ids);
}
```

UserNodeRepository#findByIdIn is custom query. but the request parameter directly **convert to json** without using ObjectIdConverter.

Log:

```
o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN {0} RETURN user with params {0=[{timestamp=1500442853, machineIdentifier=11302907, processIdentifier=11906, counter=4709865, time=1500442853000, date=1500442853000, timeSecond=1500442853}, {timestamp=1500445335, machineIdentifier=11302907, processIdentifier=11906, counter=4709946, time=1500445335000, date=1500445335000, timeSecond=1500445335}, {timestamp=1500447522, machineIdentifier=11302907, processIdentifier=11906, counter=4710014, time=1500447522000, date=1500447522000, timeSecond=1500447522}, {timestamp=1500448399, machineIdentifier=11302907, processIdentifier=11906, counter=4710092, time=1500448399000, date=1500448399000, timeSecond=1500448399}]}
```

Is this the SDN expectation or what concepts have I lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for finders with custom `@Query`. There is no way for OGM to know that your parameter relates to a property with `@Convert` annotation (the method name is not used at all). To solve this convert to your property type manually instead and use that as a parameter:

```
@Query("MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN {0} RETURN user")
List<UserNode> findByIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

However this works fine for *derived finders* - OGM knows the field, and the `@Convert` annotation with the right converter, from the method name.

Example with single parameter:

```
List<UserNode> findById(ObjectId id);
```

Unfortunately there seems to be a bug for the `IN` operator and a collection parameter with:

```
// doesn't work
List<UserNode> findByIdIn(List<ObjectId> ids);
```

I have created [a jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1018).

Comment: same bug of List<T> parameter + 1.